# jquery e.keyCode === 13 not working on modal

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

am having a modal which pull show action of rails from jvascript
in it i have a form. i want to capture enter key and prevent default submit, 
the problem is the code in the modal is not firing up when in the modal but works fine when not in the modal.

here are my code

Form

```
    <form class="new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/selfies/1/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post">
<input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓">
<input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="XtAnNJPr+yjar3BQtyVK36a28bsvUyYInDbEBg1OOQmy4ammdt9pcR/mgCD6n7XhwGoHOMIIQCNffnN5SBTeHw==">

        <textarea row="1" class="form-control" name="comment[body]" id="comment_body"></textarea>

</form>
```

here is my javascript code

```
$("#new_comment").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e && e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return $(this).submit();
    }
  });
```

and here is the form in the modal

```
<div class="lightbox" style="display: block;">


    <div class="lightbox_container">
        <div class="lightbox_container_image">
            <img src="/uploads/selfy/photo/1/20161213_123423.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="lightbox_container_meta">
          <div class="content" data-behavior="comments" data-selfie-id="1">

    <p>first comment</p>
    <p>secondly</p>
    <p>heya</p>
  </div>
  <form class="new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/selfies/1/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="XtAnNJPr+yjar3BQtyVK36a28bsvUyYInDbEBg1OOQmy4ammdt9pcR/mgCD6n7XhwGoHOMIIQCNffnN5SBTeHw==">

    <textarea row="1" class="form-control" name="comment[body]" id="comment_body"></textarea>

</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: an id is (as the name suggests) and identifier, meaning that it has to be unique. jQuery will only recognize your first form and attach events to that, the second element with the same id is not recognized anymore. You can replace the selector with `.new_comment`, a class may occur multiple times.

Comment: there is only one id in the form, #new_comment

Comment: are you using turbolinks? also, what is this modal , bootstrap?

Comment: yes am using turbolinks and this the whole javascript

`$(document).on("turbolinks:load", function() {
  
  $("#new_comment").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e && e.keyCode === 13) {
      e.preventDefault();
      return $(this).submit();
    }
  });
  
});
`
am using a modal i build

Answer (score 0):

You may try for this:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#new_comment").on("keypress", function(e) {
    if (e && e.keyCode === 13) {
       debugger;

      e.preventDefault();
      return $(this).submit();
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="lightbox" style="display: block;">


    <div class="lightbox_container">
        <div class="lightbox_container_image">
            <img src="/uploads/selfy/photo/1/20161213_123423.jpg" alt="">
        </div>
        <div class="lightbox_container_meta">
          <div class="content" data-behavior="comments" data-selfie-id="1">

    <p>first comment</p>
    <p>secondly</p>
    <p>heya</p>
  </div>
  <form class="new_comment" id="new_comment" action="/selfies/1/comments" accept-charset="UTF-8" method="post"><input name="utf8" type="hidden" value="✓"><input type="hidden" name="authenticity_token" value="XtAnNJPr+yjar3BQtyVK36a28bsvUyYInDbEBg1OOQmy4ammdt9pcR/mgCD6n7XhwGoHOMIIQCNffnN5SBTeHw==">

    <textarea row="1" class="form-control" name="comment[body]" id="comment_body"></textarea>

</form>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<p>If you click on me, I will disappear.</p>
<p>Click me away!</p>
<p>Click me too!</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

write event like this

```
$(document).on("keypress","#new_comment", function(e) {
...
}
```